# How do I create a third column in tableau that calculates the difference between this year and last year for drug purchases?

Tags: tableau-desktop

[I would like to add the third column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqUsf.png)

I have tried using this calculation lookup(sum([Purchase Dollars]),last()) - lookup(sum([Purchase Dollars]),first())

[I do not want the variance in a separate row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fbnd.png)

I also do not want to create sets for both 2022 and 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create the Calculations

We just want the sum of `[Purchase Dollars]` for a given year. So assuming you have a date field we will find the year of `TODAY()` and then return `[Purchase Dollars]` when the year of our date field matches the year of the `TODAY()` function.

First lets find the dollar amount for the current year and name it `[Current Year Purchase Dollars]` :

```
IF YEAR([your date field]) = YEAR(TODAY()) 
THEN [Purchase Dollars]
ELSE 0 #else statement is not really needed
END
```

Next lets find the dollar amount for the previous year and name it `[Previous Year Purchase Dollars]` :

```
IF DATEADD('year', -1, [your date field]) = DATEADD('year', -1, TODAY()) 
THEN [Purchase Dollars]
ELSE 0 #else statement is not really needed
END
```

Lastly we'll make a calculation to compare the difference say `[Current Year Purchase Dollar Difference]`: (feel free to come up with a shorter name)

```
[Current Year Purchase Dollars] - [Previous Year Purchase Dollars]
```

### Formatting

From the way you described it in your question it seems like you wanted all of these values displayed in a grid format. To do this, drag these three calculated field pills to the right of `[GenericName1]` on your rows shelf, right click them and choose *discrete*. You can also do this with variance and it will have it's own column.

Answer (score 1):

MUFF's answer is great, but you can also just use a Table Calculation for this particular use case.

Comment: That completely escaped me while writing this. Thank you.